# How to get all the ID's of Duplicate Name and pass it to table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

The below is the Data which i have. ProductId and Name is string datatype

```
 ProductId  Name
 "101"      John
 "201"      Marry
 "301"      Marry
 "401"      John
 "501"      John
```

I need to identify the duplicate Name and retrieve their ProductId's  and ultimately append these Id's like below structure.These result will be in DataTable(c#).

```
 ProductId             Name
"101,401,501"          John`
"201,301"              Marry
```

Please give me solution how to achieve.

Comment: What did you try and where do you have this? Do you want to deduplicate on server or using JavaScript. Please show more effort when asking

Comment: Please provide what you have tried for us to check possible errors

Comment: Please check i have edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way with `STUFF`

```
create table #MyTable(ProductId int, [Name] varchar(16))
insert into #MyTable
values
(101,'John'),
(201,'Marry'),
(301,'Marry'),
(401,'John'),
(501,'John')

select distinct
    t.[Name]
    ,ProductId = STUFF((
                      SELECT ',' + cast(t2.ProductId as char(3))
                      FROM #MyTable t2
                      WHERE t.[Name] = t2.[Name]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from
    #MyTable t


drop table #MyTable
```

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://rextester.com/URQGC4659)**

Comment: Works perfectly with the Sql server. But Please let me know how to work with c# DataTable

Comment: You tagged SQL Server 2008 so this is how you'd do this on the database side.

Comment: Yes I agree. But also i want to know how to work with c# DataTable